# Passing 3.1.3 Content-based “Reader” Apps without using IAP

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

First of all, my app include contents which are only allow to watch or access for membership subscribed user. It include 1 week, 2 weeks, 3weeks, 4 weeks and user have to pay it via other payment gateway which was popular at our country instead of IAP.

I can't use IAP because clients(users) at my country have problem with using IAP services because there is no international credit card services or payment services such as MasterCard,VIZA,etc are not supported as well. Also we can buy iTunes Gift Cards of course. But, compare it to our price subscription list, it is really too much

Here our subscriptions prize and it doesn't include auto-renew

```
1 weeks subscriptions -> $0.5
2 weeks subscriptions -> $0.9
3 weeks subscriptions -> $1.3
4 weeks subscriptions -> $1.5
```

So compare it to Apple Store Gift cards $10, that is not possible to use IAP. And at our country, giftcards are hard to buy because there is no Official Apple Store or authorized store.

To explain you about my popular payment gateway, it was like using Apple Gift Cards. It was just purchasing PIN codes from nearest Mini-marts, cafe and other shops. You can see the detail here.

http://reddotpayment.com

At my app, I included internal web view and it leads to reddot page which include textfield for PIN codes. After user fill the pin code which they bought and click subscribe, it can now part of our membership subscriptions. That's how it goes.

But Apple didn't allow and reject my app. They respond me like that.

> Guideline 3.1.1 - Business
>
> We noticed that your app enables the purchase of content, services, or
>   functionality in the app by means other than the in-app purchase API,
>   which is not appropriate for the App Store.
>
> Specifically, your app uses Red For pay to purchase subscription
>   outside the app.
>
> Next Steps
>
> While the payment system that you have included may conduct the
>   transaction outside of the app, if the purchasable content,
>   functionality, or services are intended to be used in the app, they
>   must be purchased through in-app purchase, within the app - unless it
>   is of the type referenced in guideline 3.1.3 of the App Store Review
>   Guidelines.

Was it because I do the transaction outside of the app? I mean even internal web view? What if I make the transaction inside the app with UITextField call to our API for making the purchase?

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only two ways to solve this case.

1. Use their **In-App Purchase**
2. Else try to **trick** the `Apple` with **Server-side control** especially when they are reviewing your app for App Store Distribution approval.

**Please note :**

> Using **No.2** might get your app **rejected** when they detect your app is
>   using **3rd party** payment service instead of their because they want the
>   money for each subscriptions as long as your app meant for using only
>   at your country or specific territories **not international**.

Because if you app meant for using at world-wide like Uber or Instagram, then you are at dead end.